# Slackware: losing default gateway on WiFi

Tags: linux, networking, dhcp

Since a short while, my Slackware 14.2 installation is losing its default gatweway.

The laptop connects to WiFi via wlan0. It gets the IP address, netmask, gateway and nameserver from dhcp. When the laptop is boorted and logged-in, the routing table is:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.178.1   0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 wlan0
127.0.0.0       0.0.0.0         255.0.0.0       U         0 0          0 lo
192.168.178.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 wlan0
```

which is as I expect it to be. But after a while, sometimes hours, sometimes minutes, the default-gateway is lost:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
127.0.0.0       0.0.0.0         255.0.0.0       U         0 0          0 lo
192.168.178.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 wlan0
```

The `dhcpcd.conf` is:
    # egrep -v '^#|^$' /etc/dhcpcd.conf 
    hostname
    duid
    persistent
    option rapid_commit
    option domain_name_servers, domain_name, domain_search, host_name
    option classless_static_routes
    option ntp_servers
    require dhcp_server_identifier
    slaac private
    nohook lookup-hostname
    nohook wpa_supplicant

What have I done:

I first thought it might have been an interaction problem with VirtualBox. So I rebooted, thus killing all vboxnet networks. However, that did not help.

I tried another dhcp-server. The current dhcp server is from the cable-modem, and I thought that modem might have had a problem. So I installed a dhcp-server on a raspberry pi. Same problem.

No information in the `/var/log/messages` or `/var/log/syslog`.

So, I don't know where to look.

Note that it is only the default gateway that is gone. The nameserver is still correct.

Does anyone know a solution?

Comment: When this happens, is the wifi actually still up? You should be able to ping the gateway if it still is (even if it's missing from the routing table). I suspect that your wifi is dropping out, and not reconnecting - removing the default route in this case is the correct action.

Comment: Yes, wifi is still up. I can connect to other servers within the same network segment.